# What's the best way to write my own confirm in js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to skin my own confirmation dialog using bootstrap modal without having to hook up events and without resorting to any library, except angular or jquery.

Basically, I want to be able to call something like:

```
if (myConfirm("text")) {
    // handle yes
} else {
    // handle no
};
```

myConfirm is supposed to show the modal, wait until either yes or no button was pressed and then return true or false.

What's the best way to do this?
I am not concerned at all about any IE issues.

Comment: There is no good way to do that. Make it event-based.

Comment: And why no libraries?  You can make a very nice modal dialog/confirm box using [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

Comment: This question has a practical purpose but it is actually mostly about wanting to understand js better. I want to understand if there is a way to safely circumvent the event base approach of js. BTW: colorbox is event based.

Comment: use showModalDialog to make a modal html dialog instead of confirm() that still gives you the simple non-event sync interface you crave. It's not perfect from a developer standpoint, but it's a lot better from a user standpoint than confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet for a blocking function is the old [`window.showModalDialog` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog) (which has excellent [IE support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), btw). [But you **should not use** it](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/).

Make it event-based. Especially when for learning purposes. You won't get the [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) without events. If you want a nicer abstraction, return a Promise from your function.